# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE id=20

Tags: php, mysql

How can i fix error in my sql syntax? The error is like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where id= 20' at line 11

This is the code :

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('dbConfig.php');


if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "select * from usersreg where id=".$id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'Could not select a record';
    }
}
```

Line 11 is at : `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: Aside from the error you're ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks. I'd suggest you change your PHP code to used prepared statements ASAP

Comment: Try to dump the  `$sql` so we see if the id provided is correct and like @RoryMcCrossan you should bind your parameters and escape user input!

Comment: Try this `$sql = "select * from usersreg where id=$id";`

Comment: you most likely have a hidden unicode somewhere.

Comment: studentid is the primary key in my table usersreg, not id

Comment: If you see the error message, looks like there's a space at the beginning of `$id`. A space shouldn't be a problem, but is maybe another character that is not showing correctly (\n, \t, etc). Check that.

Comment: *This* query wouldn't generate *that* error :-(

Comment: How can i define index?